# Complex string parsing for record updation

Tags: c#, regex

Consider the below input string:

```
var inputString = "Config: EbizNewTestProject.dll PaymentSOAUrl for Paid: http://111.11.11.111/Payment.asp?" + Environment.NewLine;
            inputString += "Exception: <Response> <ReturnCode>4000</ReturnCode> <SuccessCode>NO</SuccessCode> <ReturnDesc>System Error</ReturnDesc> <ReturnURL>http://localhost/Default.aspx</ReturnURL> <CustomParameter /> </Response>: " + Environment.NewLine;
            inputString += "Config: EbizNewTestProject.dll PaymentSOAUrl for Paid: http://111.11.11.111/Payment.asp? " + Environment.NewLine;
            inputString += "Exception: <Response> <ReturnCode>4000</ReturnCode> <SuccessCode>NO</SuccessCode> <ReturnDesc>System Error</ReturnDesc> <ReturnURL>http://localhost/Default.aspx</ReturnURL> <CustomParameter /> </Response>: " + Environment.NewLine;
            inputString += "Config: PartnerServicesTestBase.dll PaymentSOAUrl for Paid: https://172.31.26.38/Payment.asp? " + Environment.NewLine;
            inputString += "Exception: <Response> <ReturnCode>5000</ReturnCode> <SuccessCode>NO</SuccessCode> <ReturnDesc>System Error</ReturnDesc> <ReturnURL>http://localhost/Default.aspx</ReturnURL> <CustomParameter /> </Response>: " + Environment.NewLine;
            inputString += "Config: PartnerServicesTestBase.dll PaymentSOAUrl for Paid: https://172.31.26.38/Payment.asp? " + Environment.NewLine;
            inputString += "Exception: <Response> <ReturnCode>5000</ReturnCode> <SuccessCode>NO</SuccessCode> <ReturnDesc>System Error</ReturnDesc> <ReturnURL>http://localhost/Default.aspx</ReturnURL> <CustomParameter /> </Response>" + Environment.NewLine;
            inputString += "Config: EbizNewTestProject.dll PaymentSOAUrl for Paid: http://111.11.11.111/Payment.asp? " + Environment.NewLine;
            inputString += "Exception: <Response> <ReturnCode>4000</ReturnCode> <SuccessCode>NO</SuccessCode> <ReturnDesc>System Error</ReturnDesc> <ReturnURL>http://localhost/Default.aspx</ReturnURL> <CustomParameter /> </Response>: " + Environment.NewLine;
```

Let us observe the string content of the "Exceptions" (there are altogether 5 in the example given).

**FirstOne**

```
Exception: <Response> <ReturnCode>4000</ReturnCode> <SuccessCode>NO</SuccessCode> <ReturnDesc>System Error</ReturnDesc> <ReturnURL>http://localhost/Default.aspx</ReturnURL> <CustomParameter /> </Response>:
```

**SecondOne**

```
Exception: <Response> <ReturnCode>4000</ReturnCode> <SuccessCode>NO</SuccessCode> <ReturnDesc>System Error</ReturnDesc> <ReturnURL>http://localhost/Default.aspx</ReturnURL> <CustomParameter /> </Response>:
```

**ThirdOne**

```
Exception: <Response> <ReturnCode>5000</ReturnCode> <SuccessCode>NO</SuccessCode> <ReturnDesc>System Error</ReturnDesc> <ReturnURL>http://localhost/Default.aspx</ReturnURL> <CustomParameter /> </Response>:
```

**FourthOne**

```
Exception: <Response> <ReturnCode>5000</ReturnCode> <SuccessCode>NO</SuccessCode> <ReturnDesc>System Error</ReturnDesc> <ReturnURL>http://localhost/Default.aspx</ReturnURL> <CustomParameter /> </Response>:
```

**FifthOne**

```
Exception: <Response> <ReturnCode>4000</ReturnCode> <SuccessCode>NO</SuccessCode> <ReturnDesc>System Error</ReturnDesc> <ReturnURL>http://localhost/Default.aspx</ReturnURL> <CustomParameter /> </Response>:
```

If we look carefully, the First and Second case are identical. So are 3rd and 4th. 5th one is identical to 1st/2nd.

What I need to do is that, if the first and second or the consecutive "Exception" text's are identical, then leaving the 1st one the others will be replace with "Exception: --DO--". If an identical string is found but not consecutive, then it will appear as it is.

Henceforth, the output will be (everything of the original string will remain same only the matching exceptions will be updated as shown under)

**FirstOne**

```
Exception: <Response> <ReturnCode>4000</ReturnCode> <SuccessCode>NO</SuccessCode> <ReturnDesc>System Error</ReturnDesc> <ReturnURL>http://localhost/Default.aspx</ReturnURL> <CustomParameter /> </Response>:
```

**SecondOne (because it is identical to FirstOne and is consecutive)**

```
Exception: --DO--
```

**ThirdOne  (because it is a new one)**

```
Exception: <Response> <ReturnCode>5000</ReturnCode> <SuccessCode>NO</SuccessCode> <ReturnDesc>System Error</ReturnDesc> <ReturnURL>http://localhost/Default.aspx</ReturnURL> <CustomParameter /> </Response>:
```

**FourthOne (because it is identical to ThirdOne and is consecutive)**

```
Exception: --DO--
```

**FifthOne (though it is identical to first/second one, but not in a consecutive sequence)**

```
Exception: <Response> <ReturnCode>4000</ReturnCode> <SuccessCode>NO</SuccessCode> <ReturnDesc>System Error</ReturnDesc> <ReturnURL>http://localhost/Default.aspx</ReturnURL> <CustomParameter /> </Response>:
```

I did this program. First I get the contents of the Exceptions based on the indexes(start and end) and then stored the values inside a collection.Then using loop I was checking the content of the first and teh second and did the needed updation.

But I believe that there are many better solutions than this (may be regular expression, Linq, lambda combination.)

How can I solve this problem in an efficient way?

Comment: ... What am I not seeing?? How is the 3rd one NOT identical to the 1st & 2nd??

Comment: Edited <ReturnCode>5000</ReturnCode> for 3rd/4th while 1st/2nd/5th: <ReturnCode>4000</ReturnCode>

Comment: Ok... That at least makes more sense now :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is my final version

```
var inputString = "Config: EbizNewTestProject.dll PaymentSOAUrl for Paid: http://111.11.11.111/Payment.asp?" + Environment.NewLine;
            inputString += "Exception: <Response> <ReturnCode>4000</ReturnCode> <SuccessCode>NO</SuccessCode> <ReturnDesc>System Error</ReturnDesc> <ReturnURL>http://localhost/Default.aspx</ReturnURL> <CustomParameter /> </Response>: " + Environment.NewLine;
            inputString += "Config: EbizNewTestProject.dll PaymentSOAUrl for Paid: http://111.11.11.111/Payment.asp? " + Environment.NewLine;
            inputString += "Exception: <Response> <ReturnCode>4000</ReturnCode> <SuccessCode>NO</SuccessCode> <ReturnDesc>System Error</ReturnDesc> <ReturnURL>http://localhost/Default.aspx</ReturnURL> <CustomParameter /> </Response>: " + Environment.NewLine;
            inputString += "Config: PartnerServicesTestBase.dll PaymentSOAUrl for Paid: https://172.31.26.38/Payment.asp? " + Environment.NewLine;
            inputString += "Exception: <Response> <ReturnCode>5000</ReturnCode> <SuccessCode>NO</SuccessCode> <ReturnDesc>System Error</ReturnDesc> <ReturnURL>http://localhost/Default.aspx</ReturnURL> <CustomParameter /> </Response>: " + Environment.NewLine;
            inputString += "Config: PartnerServicesTestBase.dll PaymentSOAUrl for Paid: https://172.31.26.38/Payment.asp? " + Environment.NewLine;
            inputString += "Exception: <Response> <ReturnCode>5000</ReturnCode> <SuccessCode>NO</SuccessCode> <ReturnDesc>System Error</ReturnDesc> <ReturnURL>http://localhost/Default.aspx</ReturnURL> <CustomParameter /> </Response>: " + Environment.NewLine;
            inputString += "Config: EbizNewTestProject.dll PaymentSOAUrl for Paid: http://111.11.11.111/Payment.asp? " + Environment.NewLine;
            inputString += "Exception: <Response> <ReturnCode>4000</ReturnCode> <SuccessCode>NO</SuccessCode> <ReturnDesc>System Error</ReturnDesc> <ReturnURL>http://localhost/Default.aspx</ReturnURL> <CustomParameter /> </Response>: " + Environment.NewLine;


            TextReader reader = new StringReader(inputString);
            string line = null;
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            string firstLine = null;


            //append the first line
            sb.AppendLine(reader.ReadLine());

            //read the first exception line
            firstLine = reader.ReadLine();
            sb.AppendLine(firstLine);



            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if (line.StartsWith("Exception:"))
                {

                    if (line == firstLine)
                    {
                        sb.AppendLine("Exception:-- Do --");
                    }

                    if (line != firstLine)
                    {
                        sb.AppendLine(line);
                        firstLine = line;

                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    sb.AppendLine(line);
                }
            }


            Console.WriteLine(sb.ToString());

            Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 0):

I am still a MAJOR newbie when it comes to Regex, but it seems you could do it using them...

I'm still working on this and hoping a guru can point you in the right direction if I can't get there fast enough, but this is what I have so far:

**Regex to match:**

```
((Exception.*?)(?=Exception)){2}
```

Basically, Look for a string beginning with the word "Exception" and match everything until the next time you see the word "Exception" (but don't match the second time), then look for 2 copies of that same string.

**Regex to replace:**

```
$1Exception: --DO--
```

Meaning, keep the first time it appears and replace the second time with "Exception: --DO--"

Hope this at least starts you on the right path, I'll keep playing with it too. (Again, sorry, Regex is still fairly new to me, I just know that would be a cool solution here)

Comment: Could you please provide teh solution?

Comment: Greatest of pleasure :) - Just show exactly what you want the final output to look like (Just replace the "Exception" string or everything up until the next Exception)... Just show the start / end requirements....

Answer (score -1):

I would go over XML deserialization which handles a lot of pain for you:

imports:

```
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
```

code:

```
//find the Reponses with regex
MatchCollection  matches = Regex.Matches(inputString, "<Response>(.)+</Response>");

XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Response));

List<Response> entityList = new List<Response>();


//Deserialize the reponses
foreach (Match item in matches)
{
    using(System.IO.TextReader rdr = new StringReader(item.Value))
    {
        Response entity = (Response)serializer.Deserialize(rdr);
        entity.Line = item.Value;
        entityList.Add(entity);
    }
}

//now you have real objects which you can treat however you want. Example just a loop or linq or whatever
for (int i = 0; i < entityList.Count; i++)
{
    if (i > 0 && entityList[i - 1].ReturnCode == entityList[i].ReturnCode)
        Console.Out.WriteLine("--DO--");
    else
        Console.Out.WriteLine(entityList[i].Line);
}
```

and the entity:

```
public class Response
{
    [XmlElement("ReturnCode")]
    public int ReturnCode { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore()]
    public string Line { get; set; }
}
```